# Oracle SqlDeveloper failing on Multi-Line Execute SP with Comments: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SqlDeveloper I'm trying to execute the following multi-line SQL EXECUTE with comments,

```
execute MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, 
                    null/*Param4*/, etc.
```

On the first newline it flags the error

```
execute MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, ; END;
ORA-06550: line 1, column 131:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted st
```

and on every subsequent newline after that

```
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

There is no ; anywhere on these newlines. How I do run a multi-line formatted SQL without it complaining about newlines or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the comments. If you look at your actual error again you won't be seeing what you showed:

```
execute MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, ; END;
ORA-06550: line 1, column 131:
...
```

It will actually show:

```
BEGIN MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, ; END;
ORA-06550: line 1, column 131:
...
```

This is because [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6) is just a convenience wrapper for an anonymous block, and it only looks at the current line of your script. So it effectively runs:

```
BEGIN
  MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, ;
END;
/
```

It is adding the `BEGIN`, the trailing semicolon after the first line of your statement, and `END;`. And that is what is shown in the error message. The rest of your multiline statement is treated as independent commands, which is why they are reported as 'unknown'.

You can either manually convert your `execute` to an explicit `BEGIN`/`END;` block, or force your whole call onto a single line, or you can use the [line continuation character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-B8C7A924-216F-4E40-8D8C-0D27DE36EF96):

> You can continue a long SQL*Plus command by typing a hyphen at the end of the line and pressing Return. If you wish, you can type a space before typing the hyphen.

So you can add a hyphen at the end of each line, which will make SQL Developer (the docs are for SQL*Plus, but still apply) include all of those lines when it converts the `execute` to an anonymous block:

```
execute MYPKG.MYSP (null/*Param1*/, null/*Param2*/, 123/*Param3*/, -
                    null/*Param4*/, etc.
```

Personally I only use `exec` for quick ad hoc things, and think it's clearer and simpler to use normal, full, anonymous blocks most of the time. It also makes it easier to run your code in another client if you ever need to.

Comment: Thanks, one more issue: The last param of my SP is an OUT REFCURSOR. Before my `execute`, I have: `variable rc refcursor;` and when listing the `execute` the last param is `.. :rc );`. I got past the multi-line error with `-` like you said, but now it's giving me the error `SP2-0552: Bind variable "RC" not declared.`. I'm executing the whole block which has both the declaration and the `execute`. It's not because of the new dash `-`, is it?

Comment: No, shouldn't be. Are you running both the var and exec together as a script (F5)?

Comment: Yes, highlighted both the `variable rc refcursor` AND the next `execute` line, and the very last param of the execute is `''/*:param50*/, :rc )`;`.

Comment: Never mind, I think I had something wrong with my worksheet. Thanks for the response about the `-`.